# Middleman 4 Relative Assets Exclude Page

Tags: assets, relative-path, middleman, middleman-4

I'm trying to use the relative_assets extension in Middleman 4.2.1.

I have one page that I need to have absolute assets on, which is my /404.html page. I found the available options listed in the [source here](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/7c968b9572923fd0f7fb176ca8e52a91727adf84/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/extensions/relative_assets.rb#L3). It looks like I should be able to pass the `ignore` option an array of regexes to exclude.

I've tried to use this in my `config.rb`:

```
activate :relative_assets do |assets|
  assets.ignore = ["/404.html"]
end
```

However, I still get relative assets on the 404 page. How to properly exclude certain files from `relative_assets`?

I've also tried various other combinations such as:

```
["404"], ["/404"], ["\/404.html"], ["\/404"]
```

However, none of these seem to work either.

I have also tried [this technique](https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/middleman-4-absolute-paths-for-hashed-assets-only-on-404-page/2204) with no success. It appears that the `relative: false` option is overridden when using the relative_assets plugin for both the stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but searching for a solution to my 404 page problem led me to this question, which ultimately allowed me to solve the problem.

You want to use `rewrite_ignore` instead of `ignore`, e.g.,

`activate :relative_assets do |assets|
  assets.rewrite_ignore = [/404/, /500/]
end`

I think `ignore` by itself ignores the *asset file*.

So, hope this helps, and thank *you* for leading me the right way!